# creating a ros2 workspace

Tags: ros2

I am new to ros2 and have very little experience with it. Looking in to the documentation I have seen how to create a workspace in ros by cloning a github repository of your respective distro from their branch. Is there any other way to create a ros2 workspace with a single line terminal command similar to the one we use for creating a package in ros2. According to my knowledge I hope creating a workspace is necessary in order to create a package and run it. Thank you!

Comment: Did you already read [this](https://docs.ros.org/en/humble/Tutorials/Beginner-Client-Libraries/Creating-A-Workspace/Creating-A-Workspace.html) tutorial?

Comment: Yes, @Dave I have gone through the ROS humble documentation already. I couldn't find any other possible way other than this to create a ROS workspace. Actually the tutorial suggest cloning a GitHub repository's particular distro's branch. I would like to know if there is a command line one liner code for creating a workspace in ROS?

Comment: Basically a workspace in ROS is just a folder, which can be identified by ROS when sourcing the`install/setup.bash` file. So.. you do not need to download a pkg for creating a workspace, but just create a normal folder as you normally would do and most important create a subdirectory `src` in it, where you store your packages. Clear? Inside the 'src' folder you can then create package with `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake <package_name> Is it now clear?

Comment: Yeah, Thank you now it's clear. Actually my thought was that the concept of workspace had to do much more with a ros project rather that being just a folder. That's why I was confused when every time I wanted to create a ros workspace then I have to clone this official repo for ros with any of it's branch. But, now its clear. Thank you!

Comment: Then I move my answer above to an official answer. Please accept it, so your question does not appear under unanswered questions, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically a workspace in ROS is just a folder, which can be identified by ROS when sourcing the

> install/setup.bash

file. So.. y*ou do not need to download a pkg for creating a workspace*, but just create a normal folder as you normally would do and most important create a subdirectory `src` in it, where you store your packages. Clear? Inside the `src` folder you can then create package with `ros2 pkg create --build-type ament_cmake <package_name>`